# How can I make a singular path work correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller called `crm_controller`. It is a jumping-off point for application administrators. It has a method called `index`, which will be the home page. More will be added later.

But it's important to note that the controller is called `crm_controller`. Not `crms_controller`. It is not a resource.

All I want is for a helper method called `crm_path` to exist, and to route to `crm#index`. It has been over a year since I have created an application from scratch. I am having trouble penetrating the [routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your root path, you could do:

`get '/', to: 'crm#index', as: :crm`

You'd want to remove the `root` route from your routes file if you use the above.

Otherwise, if you have specific path you want this to land on, you could do:

`get '<path>', to: 'crm#index', as: :crm`